# Laravel 5.2 eager loading deep nested relations

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading, relation

I would like to chain some models together as following:

ContentBlock > Template > TemplateFields > FieldValue

Models:

```
class ContentBlock extends Model {
    public function template() {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\Template', 'id', 'template_id');
    }
}

class Template extends Model {
    public function templateFields() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\TemplateField', 'template_id');
    }
}

class TemplateField extends Model {
    public function fieldValue() {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\FieldValue', 'field_id');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
$contentBlock = \App\Models\ContentBlock::with('template.templateFields.fieldValue')->find(1);

dd($contentBlock->template->templateFields());
// This works
```

Now, i can go as deep as templateFields()
But if i go one relation further, i get 'BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method fieldValue does not exist'

```
dd($contentBlock->template->templateFields->fieldValue());
```

Comment: That is because there are many templatefields, and in this case you are trying to get the fieldValue of a collection, not a single row. Try to dd() without ->fieldValue appended to it.

Comment: I believe that @JanWillem is right. By $contentBlock->template->templateFields->fieldValue you are trying to use the property fieldValue of an array of objects, so you have to iterate though your templateFields array and call the fieldValue property

Comment: You are right Jan Willem.
An attempt with getting the first value of templateFields works perfectly.

$contentBlock->template->templateFields[0]->fieldValue()

Thank you !